# meson cross-file for different platforms

Tags: meson-build

In meson you specify a cross-compiler in a cross-file like:

```
[binaries]
c = '/opt/yada-yada/gcc/bin/powerpc-yada-yada-gcc'
```

This is great if you know exactly where your compiler is going to live.  If I want to specify the same compiler for Windows, I need a different cross-file like:

```
[binaries]
c = 'c:\Program Files (x86)\yada-yada\gcc\bin\powerpc-yada-yada-gcc'
```

Is there a way of using only a single cross-file for both platforms?  I thought `find_program` might help, but I just get an error about a Malformed value in cross file variable c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the entire point of cross-files is to target a specific platform. Just make a directory to keep cross-files in.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your compilers in your path, you don't need to specify an absolute path.

Then, it will work on both systems.